# Joomla Menu display in different website parts

Tags: joomla, module

I'm using Joomla 1.5 version and a strange behaviour came up regarding menus displaying.

In my default menu I have a menu item of "Front Page Blog Layout" type to display some news in my home page.

Everything was fine when I had only a menu assign for my whole website. The module that display the menu had the option "All" selected in "Menu Assignment" group.

But, when I choose the items for the menu to e displayed through "Select Menu Item(s)", the menu is not displayed when I try to see a news detail in the home page, even if I have all the items selected. It only work with "All" option selected.

Is there any difference between option "All" and select all items with the option "Select Menu Item(s)" selected?

I need this behaviour because I need several menus in my website that are displayed in different parts. Without this behaviour I can't use different menus across my website :( because some pages stay without a menu.

Any hint, workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a difference between checking "All" and marking all items in "Select Menu Item(s)".
In first case module is always displayed and in second one module checks for Itemid value. If theres no Itemid value set or it doesn't match the selected items - module is not displayed.

My suggestion is to create a new menu in menu manager, which is not displayed in any module, and assign pages to it. So every page you want a custom display would have it's own Itemid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try your approach today and give feedback

Comment: It did work. Thanks for the workarround. Now for each article I need a menu item. Is annoying

Answer (score 1):

Im glad i could help. If you assign article for a category, and make a category link in menu or hidden menu, i think it should display menu for all articles in chosen category.